# React Native doesn't update state in rendered view

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, jsx, react-navigation

I made a very basic Screen for my React Native app, which looks like this:

```
export default function DataScreen() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const data = await API.get('/data');
    console.log(data); // has the correct response
    setData(data);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{
      height: "100%",
      width: "100%"
    }}>
      {data.length > 0 && data.map(item => <Text key={item}>{item}</Text>)}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

For some reason, the `console.log` has the correct response, but the view doesn't get re-rendered once the API call is finished, so I cannot see the rendered list.

The view is accessible via a Navigator. Don't know if that makes a difference.

```
  <Tab.Navigator>
    <Tab.Screen name={data} key={"data"}>
      {DataScreen}
    </Tab.Screen>
  </Tab.Navigator>
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it the way I am calling the screen?